# How to check for the position of an Tkinter object then delete it

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

```
from tkinter import *
food_cords= []

wind = Tk()
wind.geometry("1600x850")
canvas = Canvas(wind,width = 1600,height=850)
canvaswide = [1600,850]
canvas.pack()
canvas.create_line(0,700,1600,700,fill = "black",width = 5,tag="line")

def move_right(event):
    label.place(x=label.winfo_x() + 10, y=label.winfo_y())
    x1 = label.winfo_x()
    print(x1)
    wind.update()
    if 1600 == x1:
       wind.bind("<d>", move_left) == wind.bind("<d>", nothing())

def move_left(event):
    label.place(x=label.winfo_x() - 10, y=label.winfo_y())
    x1 = label.winfo_x()
    print(x1)
wind.update()
if 0 == x1:
    wind.bind("<a>", move_left) ==  wind.bind("<a>", nothing)

def nothing(event):
    pass

wind.bind("<d>",move_right)
wind.bind("<a>",move_left)
bg = PhotoImage(file="python2.png")
mybg = canvas.create_image(0,-580,image=bg,anchor=NW)
label = Label(wind, image=bg)
label.place(x=0, y=580)
#y1 = label.winfo_y()

class Food():
    y = food_cords[0] + 20
    x = food_cords[1] - 40
    global label
    #global food_cords

    if cords == line_coordinates:
        for index in food_cords:
            if index == food_cords[0]:
                y = index + 20


                while food_cords[1] > 0:
                    x = food_cords[1] - 40
                    food_cords[1] = food_cords[1] - 100

                    oval = canvas.create_oval(0, 0, 30, 30, fill="yellow",tag="foood")
                    canvas.moveto(oval, x=x, y=y)
                    print(2312321313)
                    print(x)
                    print(label.winfo_x())
                    print(y)
                    print(label.winfo_y())
                    if x == label.winfo_x() and y == label.winfo_y:
                        print(1313123454565675643)
                        canvas.delete(oval)
                        wind.update()

                    canvas.pack()

food = Food()
wind.mainloop()
```

How can I delete the food object ( oval ) when it has the same cords as the image ( player )? It needs to delete only one food object when the player touches it. I print random numbers to see if the command works. I have posted the code above.
You move the player by hitting the keys: 'A' & 'D'
root is 'wind'

Answer (score 1):

I cleaned up some imports, your class 'Food', and added a new function to check the cords. If you have any questions about why I added or removed certain lines, please let me know. To those more experienced ... yes I know it can be more optimized and more pythonic but I did not want to stray away from the original code too much.

```
from tkinter import *
food_cords:dict= {}

wind = Tk()
wind.geometry("1600x850")
canvas = Canvas(wind,width = 1600,height=850)
canvas.pack()
canvas.create_line(0,700,1600,700,fill = "black",width = 5,tag="line")

class Food():
    for i in range(0, 10):
        x_postion: int = i * 200
        parent = Canvas(wind, width=30, height=30)
        parent.place(x=x_postion, y=660)
        oval = parent.create_oval(0, 0, 30, 30, fill="yellow",tag="foood")
        parent.update()
        food_cords[i] = [x_postion, parent]
        
    bg = PhotoImage(file="python2.png")
    mybg = canvas.create_image(0,-580,image=bg,anchor=NW)
    label = Label(wind, image=bg)
    label.place(x=0, y=580)

# !new function! 
def checkCords():
    temp = None 
    print(f"Label X: {Food.label.winfo_x()} / Label Y: {Food.label.winfo_y()}")
    for i in food_cords:
        lis = food_cords[i]
        if lis[0] == Food.label.winfo_x():
            print(f"remove food @ X:{lis[0]}")
            lis[1].delete("all")
            temp = i 
            wind.update()
    if temp != None:
        food_cords.pop(temp)


def move_right(event):
    if 1600 <= Food.label.winfo_x():
        return

    Food.label.place(x=Food.label.winfo_x() + 10, y=Food.label.winfo_y())
    x1 = Food.label.winfo_x()
    print(x1)
    wind.update()

    checkCords()

def move_left(event):
    if 0 >= Food.label.winfo_x():
        return

    Food.label.place(x=Food.label.winfo_x() - 10, y=Food.label.winfo_y())
    x1 = Food.label.winfo_x()
    print(x1)
    wind.update()

    checkCords()

wind.bind("<d>",move_right)
wind.bind("<a>",move_left)

Food()
wind.mainloop()
```